# Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?

Tags: html, dom, iframe

On Firefox and Safari, the following code displays only the first iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com"/>
<iframe src="http://www.tsr.ch"/>
```

whereas adding the closing tag solves the issue

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.tsr.ch"></iframe>
```

I don't understand why it does not work. When parsing the second example with DOMParser, it anyways does the transformation to self-closing iframes.

fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hLcukz6p/

Comment: IFrames aren't self-closing. The behaviour is by design. If DOMParser is doing it differently, it isn't following the standard

Comment: iframes and scripts do not support the self closing format. Annoying, I know. That's HTML for you :(

Comment: I wasted hours on this! So frustrating, thanks for the post and thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because the `iframe` element **isn't** a self-closing element. The versions of Firefox and Safari you're using are treating the `/>` at the end as just `>` and assuming everything after it is contained within the `iframe`.

If we attempt to pass the code you've given through [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org) we'll see the following errors:

> Error: Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.
>
> ```
> <iframe src="http://www.bing.com"/>
> ```
>
> Error: End of file seen when expecting text or an end tag.
>
> ```
> </html>
> ```
>
> Error: Unclosed element `iframe`.
>
> ```
> <iframe src="http://www.bing.com"/>
> ```

If you inspect your document with your browser's Element Inspector, you'll see what's going on.

Chrome, which I'm using, converts the invalid `<iframe ... />` to `<iframe ...></iframe>`:

[image: Chrome Example]

Comment: The browser doesn't ignore the `>`. That still marks the end of the start tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes sense. I originally had a correct closing tag. What happens is that I store this html in a database and once I retrieve it, I use DOMParser. DOMParser transforms the valid code to the invalid format unfortunately.

Comment: I am not familiar with DOMParser, but are you sure it's actually translating the HTML, and not just showing you a nearly-but-not-quite-HTML representation of the DOM tree? It can present that however it likes.

Answer (score 10):

There's no such thing as a "self-closing iframe" in HTML (or, for that matter, any other kind of self-closing tag, there are just some elements where the end tag can or must be omitted and iframe is not one of them).

You have an iframe **start tag** with an invalid `/` at the end of it.

Everything that follows is a child node of the iframe, so it treated as alternative content for browsers that don't support iframes.

---

XHTML supports self-closing tags, and any element may be added using one (if you aren't being HTML compatible).

HTML 5 allows for a `/` at the end of a start tag for an element when the end tag is omitted, but it has no effect beyond satisfying XML addiction and bad syntax highlighters.