# jQuery html() fails in case of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Actually facing a pretty strange behavior with jQuery (v1 and v2 - latest build).
I've got a script managing contents, but it fails when content contains an iframe.

```
<article>
   <section>some text with mixed tags and an <iframe /> </section>
</article>

<script>
$('section').each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).html() )
});
</script>
```

this is returning *undefined*

Am I missing some workaround to use in these cases?

Comment: You should open and close your iframe like: <iframe></iframe>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed)

Answer (score 2):

where is your <del>open</del> tag of iframe?

```
<section>some text with mixed tags and an <iframe /> </section>
```

**Update**

As @Mike c (Thanks Mike) corrected me the problem is with your self closing tag `<iframe />`

Comment: Why it was down vote? this is the cause of the problem... I will be really happy if you will explain what is the problem.

Comment: Didn't downvote but probably because `<iframe />` isn't a closing tag; it's a self-closing tag. A closing tag would be `</iframe>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kr7v77pf/3/ is example of self-closing and not, iframe tag, but got no vote :)

Comment: First of all, thanks Scion. Then I've made a little fiddle caring to replace self-closing iframes while maintaiing attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/fnc575b3/14/

Answer (score 0):

Works if written

```
<article>
<section>some text with mixed tags and an <iframe></iframe> </section>
</article>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr7v77pf/2/)