# Cannot run script after iframe

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code:

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:500px;"/>
<script>console.log("prpr")</script>
```

when i run `google-chrome /home/roroco/Dropbox/jss/ro-wemedia/ex/test-keydown-for-iframe.html`, I doesn't find any output in chrome console, how to run script after iframe?

Comment: Wrong dupe, @Quentin. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27545757/560648.

Answer (score 10):

Your `iframe`is not closed.

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:500px;"></iframe>
<script>console.log("prpr")</script>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `<iframe></iframe>` is the correct syntax. :)

Comment: Correct; an iframe isn't a self-closing element.