# Iframe ejecution stops php

Tags: php, html, iframe

I've been trying to set an iframe in the middle of my php code but it make my php code get off;

Code tested:

```
<?php
    $pdf = "";

    $pdf.= "hola <br>";
    $pdf.= "<iframe src='https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/Cartografia/mapa.aspx?refcat=001901800VM18D0001OS' width='500' height='500' align='center' />";
    $pdf.= "<br> hola2";


    echo $pdf;
```

Couldn't find why this page get stopped my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $url = "https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/Cartografia/mapa.aspx?refcat=001901800VM18D0001OS";
if (isset ($url)) { // decode the url and display it in the iframe
            $pdf .= ' hola<br>';
            $pdf .= '<iframe  src="'.urldecode($url).'"></iframe>';
            $pdf .= '<br> hola2';
            echo $pdf;
     } else { // display a static page if no url parameter was received
           $pdf .=  ' hola <br>';
           $pdf .=  '<iframe src="http://myurl.com/mycontent.html"></iframe>';
           $pdf .=  '<br> hola2';
           echo $pdf;
        }
  ?>
```

working fine

http://phpfiddle.org/