# Adding Discord widget/iframe stops web page loading

Tags: html, discord

I have a web-app that loads fine.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/xBBBxQ

When I add the following widget...

```
<iframe class="discord" src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=201798443583143936&theme=dark"/>
```

... the loader page will hang infinitely.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/VRRRjZ

It doesn't matter where I put the widget, the page doesn't load. The widget doesn't need any libraries or dependencies. I already have an iframe on the page that loads a youtube video.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframe` element isn't a self-closing element.

Try:
`<iframe class="discord" src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=201798443583143936&theme=dark"></iframe>`

Comment: Interesting. A non-closing iframe works fine in this demo: https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/NJJLKz but it definitely is better to close the frame. Maybe it works in the demo because there are no other elements on the page