# HTML cannot display footer on page

Tags: html, css, position, footer, visibility

Im trying to create a web page and add more content. Im trying to add a footer but it wont show up. This my code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Fedorfanpage</title>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="h1" >Fedor Emelianenko Fan page</h1>
    
    
    <div class = "box1"> 
      Fedor career highlights
      <ul class = "ul.a">
      <li>Pride Heavyweight Champion</li>
      <li>Fias World Combat Sambo Champion</li>
      <li>Russian Federation Judo National Champion</li>
      <li>Wamma World Champion</li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class = "box2">
      <p class="p1">
      Fedor Vladimirovich Emelianenko, is widely regarded as the greatest mixed martial arts fighter of all time. Fedor was born in Rubizhne, which is the small town in the Ukrainian SSR, a former Soviet republic. He has two brothers and one sister, one of the brothers Alexander is also a mma fighter. Fedor nad his brother trained Sambo from a very young age. The two would pratice their throws four hours at a time. Later in life, Fedor went to school to pursue a trade and joined the army. In the Russian army, Fedor was a military firefighter and part of tank division. After Fedor had left the military, he joined the National team for Judo. There was no money in competing for the national team, so Fedor had to apply his skills elsewhere. In the year 2000, he had his first MMA fight for the rings organization and would go on to be their heavyweight champion.
      </p>
     
    </div>
    <div class = "box3"><p1 class = "tag" >"The Last Emperor"</p1></div>
    <div class = "box4"> <p2 class = "par2">This is the ultimate highlight video of Fedor Emelianenko's storied career. It shows some of first matches in Rings all the way through pride at the height of his career. It also shows some of his time when he came to America at the end.</p2><iframe class ="fedorhighlight" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5ivjn4zETUM"/> 
      
    </div>
  <div class="foot1"> A page created by Colton Farbatuk, 2020. </div>   
    
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css

```
html{
   position:relative;
   min-height:100%;
 }
#h1{
    color:red;
    font-family:"Brush script MT",cursive;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border:solid black;
    background:white;

}
body
{
  background-image:url(Russiaflagbackground.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    
    
}

.box1{
      background-image:url(pride.jpg);
      background-size:cover;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      float:left;
      padding:10px;
      border:solid red;
      font-family:'Times New Roman';
      text-shadow: black 0px 0px 10px;
      font-weight:bold;
      color:crimson;
      
     
}
.box2{
  
  width:600px;
  height:250px;
  padding:10px;
  float:right;
  border:solid red;
  color:blueviolet;
  background:white;
  font-family:fantasy;
  margin-right:250px;
  
}
.p1{
    text-align:justify;
    padding:10px;
    
    
    
    
}
.box3{
      z-index:-1;
      position:relative;
      left:0px;
      bottom:-300px;
      height:250px;
      width:200px;
      border:solid red;
      padding:10px;
      background-image:url(fedormug.jpg);
      background-size:cover;
      
}

ul.a{
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-left:0 px;
  
}
.tag{
  position:relative;
  text-align:justify;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  left:15px;
}


.box4{
  
  width:800px;
  height:250px;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  border:solid red;
  font-family:fantasy;
  left: 456px;
  bottom:-25px;
  background:red;
  float:left;

}

.par2{
  color:white;
  text-emphasis:bold;
  float:right;
  justify-content:right;
  left:200px;
  display:flex;
}
.fedorhighlight{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  float:left;
  overflow:auto;
}
.foot1{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  color:red;
  border: solid black;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  height:50 px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
}
```

so i cant get a footer to show up at all, if i move the footer inside one of the divs then it will work if i position it down far enough. Is there a way to do it as ive shown here?

Answer (score 0):

You've left the iframe open.  It just needs needs a closing tag and the rest of the page will render properly below.

Here's a bit more background -
[Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed)