# Why do tags don't work when they are aligned below an "iframe" or "object" tag?

Tags: html

```
<iframe src="learning.pdf">

<div>test<div>

<video controls>

    <source src="somevideo" type="video/webm">  

</video>
```

All the tags below the "iframe" or "object" tag just don't work. If i put them at the end of the tree, all the above tags work, or if i put them in the middle of several tags, all the tags below the iframe or object tags don't work, but the ones above them, work.

```
<div>test<div>

<video controls>

    <source src="somevideo" type="video/webm">  

</video> 

<object data="learning.pdf">

<div>test<div>

<audio controls>

    <source src="some song.mp3">

</audio>
```

Why?

Comment: Use a html validator.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed)

Comment: @D.Pardal No. This is not a self-closing iframe tag.

Comment: Closing the tag doesn't change anything. Iframe itself is a self-closing tag, and the same issue does not appear when using other self-closing tags like "input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't close your `iframe` tag, so all your subsequent content is *within it* (and ignored*, because the actual content of the iframe is taken from "learning.pdf").

Don't self-close it, either; [it has to be accompanied by a proper `</iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27545757/4386278):

```
<iframe src="learning.pdf"></iframe>

<div>test<div>

<video controls>

    <source src="somevideo" type="video/webm">  

</video>
```

When in doubt, [**validate your HTML**](https://validator.w3.org/).

---

* More accurately, it's treated as alternative content for browsers that don't support iframes.

Comment: Closing the tag doesn't change anything. Iframe itself is a self-closing tag, and the same issue does not appear when using other self-closing tags like "input".

Comment: @Uchujin [No, it isn't.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element) **Validate your HTML.** (Comparisons to `input` are irrelevant anyway, as they can't "contain" things the way `iframe` does for alternative content.)

Comment: Sorry, i stand corrected. Closing iframe did fix the issue, but isn't iframe a self-closing tag?

Comment: Once again, no, it is not.

Comment: I don't think comparing input is irrelevant because iframe's content is not contained within its brackets, it's imported externally.

Comment: Why did you come here asking for information and advice from the experts, if you're going to disbelieve it all? ‍♂️ Good luck.

Comment: Just for the record, i don't disbelieve you. I am just saying that the comparison between input and iframe was relevant, since the iframe content is not contained within its brackets.

Comment: It isn't, for the reason I gave.