# HTML::TreeBuilder extract title tag failing on some sites

Tags: perl

I'm trying to work out why this code fails in some edge cases:

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use Data::Dumper;

my $page = `curl -H "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9; PageThing http://pagething.com) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0" --compressed --silent --max-time 10 --location --connect-timeout 10 'weboost.com'`;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($page);
my $title = $root->look_down( '_tag', 'title' );

print Dumper($title); # comes back as undef
my $page_title =  $title->as_text;
print "BLA: $page_title\n";
```

I get:

```
Can't call method "as_text" on an undefined value at test.cgi line 28.
```

I have confirmed the `<title>` exists :

```
<title>weBoost</title>
```

So why isn't it finding it?

Comment: Choose small pase with such problem and dump the parsed tree - it may give you a hint. `$root->dump(); # prints dump to STDOUT`

Comment: Faced with this, I'd dump the text that curl retrieved and look through it manually, first of all. If you already did that, my apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML of this site is wrong. It uses a self-closing iframe, which is invalid according to the HTML specification:

```
<iframe src="..." height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" />
                                                                             ^^^^
```

Since it is invalid the self-closing will be ignored, i.e. everything after the iframe tag will be considered part of the iframe until an explicit `</iframe>` will be found. This can also be seen when doing a `$root->dump`:

```
<html> @0
  ...
    <iframe height="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TQ5LT9K" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"> @0.1.0
      "</noscript><meta name="description" content="weBoost cell phone s..."
```

For more information see also [Why is a self-closing iframe tag preventing further DOM elements to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545757/why-is-a-self-closing-iframe-tag-preventing-further-dom-elements-to-be-displayed).

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. Thought it might be something like that. I'll just ignore than one then. Its happened on a few sites, but looking at the quality of peoples HTML on their sites - I'm amazed it doesn't happen more!

Answer (score 2):

[Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) doesn't have this effect because it cares less about "correct" (or, as it says, it's a "relaxed" parser). Not only that, but you can easily do everything inside Perl:

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new->max_redirects(3);
$ua->transactor->name( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9; PageThing http://pagething.com) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0" );

my $url = 'weboost.com';
my $tx = $ua->get(
    $url =>
    { 'Accept-Charset' => 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7' }
    );

say $tx->result->dom->at( 'title' )->text;
```

This outputs the text in `title`:

```
weBoost
```

I have plenty of more examples of Mojo web client tricks in [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients). Many of the things that you can do in `curl` are easy to type out in Mojo.